# How can I parse objects from @message in AWS' Logs Insights?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have log entries in the following format:

```
2022-07-14T15:08:05.372Z ffcb7ee9-0e73-42d9-a236-d90fb1dfb131 ERROR {"level":"error","timestamp":"\"2022-07-14T15:08:05.372Z\"", ..., "log":"{\"message\":{\"statusCode\":400, ...}
```

So it is basically: `[timestamp] [id] [messageType] [JSONobject]`.

I would like to extract the object part as an accessible object. I have looked in multiple questions suggesting how to do it, but nothing works for me.

I tried:

`parse @message '* * ERROR {"*"}' as ts, id, dataObj` // all declared fields show empty

`parse @message '* * ERROR *' as ts, id, dataObj` // all declared fields show empty

`parse @message '* * * *' as ts, id, ty, dataObj` // here in the first field appears string containing `[timestamp] [id] [messageType] [aPartOfObject]` and the following fields contain some other parts of the JSON.

`parse @message 'ERROR *' as dataObj` // dataObject field comes empty

`parse @message '{"*"}' as dataObj` // dataObject field contains 'faulty' JSON string starting with first property name without the opening quotation mark `level:"...`

`parse @message '{*}' as dataObj` // similar as above, but starting with quotation mark: `"level:"...`

Before the parsing line I include `filter @message like 'ERROR'` to ensure only these logs get parsed.

Why is it not working as expected? How can I make it work?

Comment: could you add the full message object here?

Comment: @DeivisonSporteman I'm not sure, since we refactored the logged content, but it might have looked something like this: `2022-10-25T15:20:44.900Z 9a2280e5-af06-4e46-b1a6-fb99bb72c5af ERROR 
{
    "level": "error",
    "timestamp": "\"2022-10-25T15:20:44.900Z\"",
    "service": "charge-orders",
    "market": "pl",
    "log": "{ \"message\": {\"statusCode\": 400, \"message\": \"Some message\"} }
}`

Comment: I see, and you still have issues?

Comment: @DeivisonSporteman We flattened the logged message so that all properties are on the message level, so they are automatically split by AWS. So we technically don't have the issue anymore, as it is a working workaround, but the question remain valid for cases where it might be not possible for whatever reason.